# What is httpinterceptor equivalent in angular2?

Tags: http, angular

In angularjs, we have http interceptor

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

with which we can hook into all http calls, and show or hide loading bars, do logging, etc..

What is the equivalent in angular2?

Comment: http://array151.com/blog/http-interceptor-hijack-http-request-and-response-in-angular-2/

Answer (score 62, accepted):

As @Günter pointed it out, there is no way to register interceptors. You need to extend the `Http` class and put your interception processing around HTTP calls

First you could create a class that extends the `Http`:

```js
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```js
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

The `request` and `requestError` kinds could be added before calling the target methods.

For the `response` one, you need to plug some asynchronous processing into the existing processing chain. This depends on your need but you can use operators (like `flatMap`) of Observable.

Finally for the `responseError` one, you need to call the `catch` operator on the target call. This way you will be notified when an error occurs in the response.

This links could help you:

- [Handling refresh tokens using rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907151/handling-refresh-tokens-using-rxjs)
- [Angular 2 - How to get Observable.throw globally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439672/angular-2-how-to-get-observable-throw-globally/35439805#35439805)

Comment: A great explanation, another good explanation i found : https://www.illucit.com/blog/2016/03/angular2-http-authentication-interceptor/

Comment: bootstrapping doesn't seem to work this way anymore in angular2.

Comment: This solution does not work anymore. Bootstrapping has changed. Can you update the answer accordingly?

Answer (score 19):

**update**

The new `HttpClient` module introduced in Angular 4.3.0 supports interceptors https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/4.3.0-rc.0...4.3.0

> **feat(common):** new HttpClient API HttpClient is an evolution of the
>   existing Angular HTTP API, which exists alongside of it in a separate
>   package, @angular/common/http. This structure ensures that existing
>   codebases can slowly migrate to the new API.
>
> The new API improves significantly on the ergonomics and features of
>   the legacy API. A partial list of new features includes:
>
> - Typed, synchronous response body access, including support for JSON body types
> - JSON is an assumed default and no longer needs to be explicitly parsed
> - Interceptors allow middleware logic to be inserted into the pipeline
> - Immutable request/response objects
> - Progress events for both request upload and response download
> - Post-request verification & flush based testing framework

**original**

Angular2 doesn't have (yet) interceptors. You can instead extend `Http`, `XHRBackend`, `BaseRequestOptions` or any of the other involved classes (at least in TypeScript and Dart (don't know about plain JS).

See also

- [RFC: Http interceptors and transformers](https://github.com/angular/http/issues/80)
- [Introduce an interception mechanism](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2893)
- [Interceptors in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355754/interceptors-in-angular2)
- [Angular2 - set headers for every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34464108/angular2-set-headers-for-every-request/34465070#34465070)

Answer (score 12):

There's an implementation for a Http @angular/core-like service in this repository: https://github.com/voliva/angular2-interceptors

You just declare the provider for that service on bootstrap, adding any interceptors you need, and it will be available for all the components.

```js
import { provideInterceptorService } from 'ng2-interceptors';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [
    MyHttpInterceptor,
    provideInterceptorService([
      MyHttpInterceptor,
      /* Add other interceptors here, like "new ServerURLInterceptor()" or
         just "ServerURLInterceptor" if it has a provider */
    ])
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Answer (score 11):

**DEPRICATED SINCE Angular 4.3 (HttpInterCeptors are Back in 4.3)**

You can create your own custom HTTP Class and use rxjs Subject Service to reuse your custom Http Class and implement your behaviors in a custom class.

Implementation of your Custom Http Class with "HttpSubjectService" which contains some rxjs Subjects.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


import { HttpSubjectService } from './httpSubject.service';


@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
   constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, private httpSubjectService: HttpSubjectService) {
       super(backend, defaultOptions);

       //Prevent Ajax Request Caching for Internet Explorer
       defaultOptions.headers.append("Cache-control", "no-cache");
       defaultOptions.headers.append("Cache-control", "no-store");
       defaultOptions.headers.append("Pragma", "no-cache");
       defaultOptions.headers.append("Expires", "0");
   }

   request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
       //request Start;
       this.httpSubjectService.addSpinner();
       return super.request(url, options).map(res => {
           //Successful Response;
           this.httpSubjectService.addNotification(res.json());
           return res;
       })
           .catch((err) => {
               //Error Response.
               this.httpSubjectService.removeSpinner();
               this.httpSubjectService.removeOverlay();

               if (err.status === 400 || err.status === 422) {
                   this.httpSubjectService.addHttp403(err);
                   return Observable.throw(err);
               } else if (err.status === 500) {
                   this.httpSubjectService.addHttp500(err);
                   return Observable.throw(err);
               } else {
                   return Observable.empty();
               }
           })
           .finally(() => {
               //After the request;
               this.httpSubjectService.removeSpinner();
           });
   }
}
```

Custom module to register your CustomHttp class - here you overwrite the default Http implementation from Angular with your own CustomHttp Implementation.

```js
import { NgModule, ValueProvider } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule, Http, XHRBackend, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

//Custom Http
import { HttpSubjectService } from './httpSubject.service';
import { CustomHttp } from './customHttp';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ ],
    providers: [
        HttpSubjectService,
        {
           provide: Http, useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions, httpSubjectService: HttpSubjectService) => {
                return new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions, httpSubjectService);
            },
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions, HttpSubjectService]
        }
    ]
})
export class CustomHttpCoreModule {

    constructor() { }
}
```

now we need the HttpSubjectService Implementation where we can SubScribe to our rxjs Subjects when they get called with the "next" statement.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class HttpSubjectService {
    //https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/subject.md
    //In our app.component.ts class we will subscribe to this Subjects
    public notificationSubject = new Subject();
    public http403Subject = new Subject();
    public http500Subject = new Subject();
    public overlaySubject = new Subject();
    public spinnerSubject = new Subject();

    constructor() { }

    //some Example methods we call in our CustomHttp Class
    public addNotification(resultJson: any): void {
        this.notificationSubject.next(resultJson);
    }

    public addHttp403(result: any): void {
        this.http403Subject.next(result);
    }

    public addHttp500(result: any): void {
        this.http500Subject.next(result);
    }

    public removeOverlay(): void {
        this.overlaySubject.next(0);
    }

    public addSpinner(): void {
        this.spinnerSubject.next(1);
    }

    public removeSpinner(): void {
        this.spinnerSubject.next(-1);
    }
}
```

to call your custom Implementations we need to Subscribe to the Subjects in the e.g. "app.component.ts".

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpSubjectService } from "../HttpInterception/httpSubject.service";
import { Homeservice } from "../HttpServices/home.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
    private locals: AppLocalsModel = new AppLocalsModel();

    constructor(private httpSubjectService : HttpSubjectService, private homeService : Homeservice) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.notifications();
        this.httpRedirects();
        this.spinner();
        this.overlay();
    }

    public loadServiceData(): void {
        this.homeService.getCurrentUsername()
            .subscribe(result => {
                this.locals.username = result;
            });
    }

    private overlay(): void {
        this.httpSubjectService.overlaySubject.subscribe({
            next: () => {
              console.log("Call Overlay Service");
            }
        });
    }

    private spinner(): void {
        this.httpSubjectService.spinnerSubject.subscribe({
            next: (value: number) => {
              console.log("Call Spinner Service");
            }
        });
    }

    private notifications(): void {
        this.httpSubjectService.notificationSubject.subscribe({
            next: (json: any) => {
                console.log("Call Notification Service");
            }
        });
    }

    private httpRedirects(): void {
        this.httpSubjectService.http500Subject.subscribe({
            next: (error: any) => {
                console.log("Navigate to Error Page");
            }
        });

        this.httpSubjectService.http403Subject.subscribe({
            next: (error: any) => {
                console.log("Navigate to Not Authorized Page");
            }
        });
    }
}


class AppLocalsModel {
    public username : string = "noch nicht abgefragt";
}
```

**SINCE ANGULAR 4.3 you can Use InterCeptors**

In Angular 4.3 you have native Interceptors where you can implement your own stuff like a redirect for server error 500

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()
export class SxpHttp500Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(public router: Router) { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
      return next.handle(req).do(evt => { }).catch(err => {
          if (err["status"]) {
              if (err.status === 500) {
                  this.router.navigate(['/serverError', { fehler: JSON.stringify(err) }]);
              }
          }
          return Observable.throw(err);
      });
  }
}
```

you need to Register this in your core module in the providers Array

```
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { SxpHttp500Interceptor } from "./sxpHttp500.interceptor";
 ....

providers: [
    {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useFactory: (router: Router) => { return new SxpHttp500Interceptor(router) },
        multi: true,
        deps: [Router]
    }
]
```

Comment: Native Interceptors will be avaible perhaps on angular 4.1 => https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2684#issuecomment-281725838

Comment: Could be a more concise answer, but a neat approach overall.

Answer (score 8):

With the Angular 4.3.1 release, there's now an interface called **HttpInterceptor**.

Here's the link to the docs: 
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor

## Here's an implementation sample.

---

#### This would be the interceptor class implementation.

Is basically written as any other service:

```
@Injectable()
export class ExceptionsInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private logger: Logger,
        private exceptionsService: ExceptionsService,
        private notificationsService: NotificationsService
    ) { }
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        return next.handle(request)
            .do((event) => {
                // Do nothing here, manage only errors
            }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                if (!this.exceptionsService.excludeCodes.includes(err.status)) {
                    if (!(err.status === 400 && err.error['_validations'])) {
                        this.logger.error(err);
                        if (!this.notificationsService.hasNotificationData(err.status)) {
                            this.notificationsService.addNotification({ text: err.message, type: MessageColorType.error, data: err.status, uid: UniqueIdUtility.generateId() });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Then since you'll treat this like a normal service, you have to add this line inside your app module's providers:

```
{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ExceptionsInterceptor, multi: true }
```

Hope it can help.

Comment: And, where is the implementation?

Comment: Useful imports: `import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";`, `import { HttpErrorResponse, HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";`

Comment: NotificationsService is not working globaly..Any suggestion? https://github.com/flauc/angular2-notifications

Answer (score 3):

**Angular 4.3** now supports Http interceptor out-of-the-box.
Check it out how to use them: 
https://ryanchenkie.com/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors

Answer (score 0):

I have released interceptor with following node module. We was create this  module for our internal purpose finally we released in npm package manager 
**npm install angular2-resource-and-ajax-interceptor**
**https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-resource-and-ajax-interceptor**

Answer (score 0):

As @squadwuschel pointed out, work is underway to get this functionality into @angular/http.  This will be in the form of a new HttpClient API.

See https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/17143 for more details and current status.

Answer (score 0):

Try  [Covalent from  Teradata](https://teradata.github.io/covalent), they provides lots of extensions for  Angular and Angular Material.

Check [HTTP](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/http) part, it provides the missing http interceptor in Angular and RESTService(similar to restangular).

I have implemented JWT token authentication via  [Covalent HTTP](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components/http)  in my sample, Please check here.

https://github.com/hantsy/angular2-material-sample/blob/master/src/app/core/auth-http-interceptor.ts

Read my development notes for it, [Handle token based Authentication via IHttpInterceptor](https://github.com/hantsy/angular2-sample/wiki/auth-http).

Comment: BTW, Angular 4.3  was just released, it includes the new Http Client( [#37797e2](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/37797e2)), I think we do not need the 3rd party tools or custom HTTP now.

Comment: This might help: https://modewagon.wordpress.com/2017/09/13/angular-4-http-interceptor/

Answer (score 0):

Angular2 donot support httpinterceptor like angular1

Here is awesome example of use of httpinterceptor in angular2.

https://github.com/NgSculptor/ng2HttpInterceptor