# Intercepting errors in Angular2 - issue with catch

Tags: angular, interceptor

I was following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498456/what-is-httpinterceptor-equivalent-in-angular2) by `Thierry Templier`, but run into some troubles when defining error interceptors (***other interceptors are working***).

I have the following:

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
  console.log('get...');
  return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
    this.router.navigate(['Login']);
    return Observable.of(res)
  });
}
```

Which throws :

> vendor.min.js:38333 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError:
>   _super.prototype.get.call(...).catch is not a function

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you perhaps forgot the import the `catch` operator in the module where you define the interceptor class:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
```

Comment: Any idea why am I getting ' TypeError: result.subscribe is not a function' errors, (exactly the same example as in question)

Comment: I think that you could try this: `return Observable.of(res);` instead of `return res;`

Comment: amazing! where do you have all of this knowledge from? can you point any good books/articles? it seems like you are waaay ahead of curve :)

Comment: I played a lot with rxjs ;-) These two links could interest you: http://slides.com/robwormald/everything-is-a-stream and https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754. They are amazing!

Comment: whenever I am inside of my 'catch', I lose access to 'this'. Do you have any ideas on how to overcome this?

Comment: Thierry, do you mind looking at a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911993/intercepting-errors-and-subscribing-to ?