# Intercepting errors and subscribing to

Tags: angular

I have an issue with subscribing in the right way to my http interceptor. I have the following:

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>{
     return super.post(url,body, {headers: customHeaders}).catch(err =>{
            console.log('Error caught in POST at '+url);
            return Observable.of(err);
        });
    }
```

Which is fine - it logs each time there was an error while posting. However, if I try to catch error in other component like this:

```
this.http.post('someurl','somestring')
    .subscribe(
        success=>{
            console.log('success: ',success);
        },
        error=>{
            console.log('error: ',error);
        }
    )
```

So now, when there is an error in POST my console log prints:

```
Error caught in POST at someurl
success: //errorobject here//
```

However, I was expecting this:

```
Error caught in POST at someurl
error: //errorobject here//
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be `throw err` instead of `Observable.of(err)`

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>{
     return super.post(url,body, {headers: customHeaders}).catch(err =>{
            console.log('Error caught in POST at '+url);
            throw err;
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Observable.throw` instead of `Observable.of`:

```
post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response>{
  return super.post(url,body, {headers: customHeaders}).catch(err =>{
        console.log('Error caught in POST at '+url);
        return Observable.throw(err); // <--------------
    });
}
```

`Observable.of` returns a "successful" observable so it will be handled by the success callback within `subscribe`.

Comment: Thierry, I've gone one for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049848/http-stream-send-twice-instead-of-once :)