# Http stream send twice instead of once

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am wondering what is wrong with my code. I have the following in my service:

```
updateCollection(){
    var updateStream = this._http.get('someApi')
        .map((res)=>{
            return res.json();
        })

    updateStream.subscribe(
        success=> {
            this.collection.length = 0;
            console.log('Success in getting collection: ', success.collection);
            (<any>Object).assign(this.collection, success.collection);
            return this.collection;
        }
    );

    return updateStream;
}

getCollection(){
    return this.updateCollection();
}
```

And in my component, I have defined:

```
this._service.getCollection()
        .subcribe(
            success=>{
                console.log("In component", success)
            }
)
```

However, as I can see from my chrome network and debuggin, it seems that:

```
this._http.get('someApi')
```

is called twice, instead of once.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

That's because you `subscribe()` twice. Once inside `updateCollection()` and once in `getCollection()`.

This should do what you want:

```
updateCollection(){
    return this._http.get('someApi')
        .map((res)=>{
           let result = res.json();
           this.collection.length = 0;
           console.log('Success in getting collection: ', success.collection);
            (<any>Object).assign(this.collection, success.collection);
           return result;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          return Observable.of([]); to silently continue
          // or return Observable.throw(error);
          // or just throw error;
        });
}
```

ensure you have everything imported

```
import 'rxjs'
```

or

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'
```

Comment: is there a way then to catch error within the map method?

Comment: I udpated my answer.