# Success / Error Reporting from Service with Events / Observables

Tags: angularjs, angular, observable, dom-events

Using some documentation I found online, I've written a service method for saving some data like this:

```
@Injectable
export class BrandService {

  brands$: Observable<Brand[]>;
  private _brandsObserver: Observer<Brand[]>;
  private _dataStore: {
      brands: Brand[]
  };

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.brands$ = new Observable(observer => this._brandsObserver = observer).share();
    this._dataStore = { brands: []};
  }

  saveBrand(brand: Brand) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/brands", JSON.stringify(brand), { headers: headers })
       .map( (response: Response) => response.json()).subscribe(
           data => {
             this._dataStore.brands.push(data);
             this._brandsObserver.next(this._dataStore.brands);
           }, 
           error => console.log("Could not create Brand"));
  }
}
```

What this allows me to do is push updates to my collection of Brands and my table on the view will observe these changes and update automatically so I don't have to manually refresh it. All is well with the world.

My problem is that since I'm subscribing to the `http.post` in the service, my component now has no way of knowing whether or not this call succeeded, which also means that, since I'm showing the form in a modal dialog, I don't know if I should close the dialog or display errors. My component simply does this...

```
this._brandService.saveBrand(this.brandForm.value);
```

So, I was thinking that I should figure out a way to a) fire an event in the service that I'm listening for in the component for when good / bad things happen and act accordingly, or b) figure out some way of observing some other properties in the service that I can act on when those changes are detected. But I'm pretty new to all this observable stuff and I don't really even know where to begin.

```
data => {
  this._dataStore.brands.push(data);
  this._brandsObserver.next(this._dataStore.brands);
  // fire some success event or
  // update some observed property
}, 
error => {
  // fire some failure event or
  // update some observed property
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the `subscribe()` at call site

```
saveBrand(brand: Brand) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/api/brands", JSON.stringify(brand), { headers: headers })
       .map( (response: Response) => response.json()).map(
           data => {
             this._dataStore.brands.push(data);
             this._brandsObserver.next(this._dataStore.brands);
           });
  }
```

```
this._brandService.saveBrand(this.brandForm.value)
.subscribe(
    value => onSuccess(),
    error => onError());
```

If you still want to do some generic error handling in `saveBrand` you can use the `catch` operator (like used in [Intercepting errors and subscribing to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36911993/intercepting-errors-and-subscribing-to))

Comment: Holy cow. So simple. Completely didn't realize I could chain maps in this situation. Thanks!