# BaseResponseOptions angular2 Handling global error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angular

Hi I want to handle a global 401 error after an http request with angular2. I want to extend BaseResponseOptions class. This is the corret way?

Comment: Looks like a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498456/what-is-httpinterceptor-equivalent-in-angular2/35499034#35499034

Answer (score 1):

You could extend rather the `Http` class itself to handle such error globally. This way you will be able to leverage the `catch` operator on the underlying requests and catch 401 errors.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
  }

  request(url: string | Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('request...');
    return super.request(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });        
  }

  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    console.log('get...');
    return super.get(url, options).catch(res => {
      // do something
    });
  }
}
```

and register it as described below:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    new Provider(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
      deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

Using only response options you won't be able to intercept requests / responses.