# How to implement Interceptor for refreshing token when api response status is 401 in angular 2

Tags: angular

Am New to Angualr 2 , am facing problem while refreshing the Token when api response is Non authorized (401 ) error. What want implement this concept by using interceptor .  Please suggest any inputs or Suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 we don't have a concept of interceptors, the same can we achieved by creating a custom http service which extends the standard http service. And when in your app module you can direct angular to use your custom http service wherever the http service is required.

Comment: For a detailed answer you can see the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498456/what-is-httpinterceptor-equivalent-in-angular2

Comment: Thanks for replay, below code am using to refresh token this._http.get(url,{ headers: headers })
            .map((res: Response) =>{return res.json()})
            .catch(error=>{
                if(error.status=401&&this.refreshTokenCount<=3)
                {
                 
                 }
})

Answer (score 0):

Below Code will help to achieve the refresh token  Intercepter
 ` get(url:string) : Observable {

```
    let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.token});
    return this._http.get(url, {headers: headers})
        .map((res: Response) => {
            return res;
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            if (error.status === 401) {
                return this.RefreshToken().flatMap((newToken) => {
                    let newheaders = new Headers({
                        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
                        'Authorization': 'bearer ' + this.token
                    });
                    return this._http.request(url, {headers: newheaders});
                })
            } else {
                return Observable.throw(error);
            }
        });
} `
```

Comment: I'd like to add one remark. For example if you use JWT, you'd still need a valid token in order to refresh it. As I researched myself on this topic, the best practice would be to refresh the token n minutes/hours before it will have expired.

Answer (score 0):

You can better handle the 401 unathorized in subscribe, below is the code, you can use it in the component itself

```
this.dynamic.getProfileDetails(this.userId, this.password).subscribe(
      v => (this.firstName = v.firstName),
      (err) => {
        // check if it is 401 and the token is invalid
        if (err.status == 401 && err.json().oauth2ErrorCode=='invalid_token') {
          console.log("Error Description " + err.json().oauth2ErrorCode);
          console.log("inside component error");
          //  refresh the token
          console.log("refresh the token")
          this._getNewToken.getNewTokenService().subscribe(
            v => {
              //  token is refreshed so retry the original request
              console.log("retry the original request with the new acces token")
              this.dynamic.getProfileDetails(this.userId, this.password).subscribe(
                v => (this.firstName = v.firstName)
              )
            },
            (refreshErr) => {
              if(refreshErr.status == 401 && refreshErr.json().oauth2ErrorCode=='invalid_token')
              {
                console.log("refresh token 401"+refreshErr.json().oauth2ErrorCode);
                this._router.navigate(['login']);
              }
              else if(refreshErr.status==400)
              {
                console.log("inside 400 "+refreshErr );
                this._router.navigate(['login']);
              }
              else
              {
                console.log("error des "+refreshErr );
                this._router.navigate(['login']);
              }
            }
          );



        }
        else{
               //serve  error logout from the app
                this._router.navigate(['login']);
               console.log("server error");
        }
      }
    );
```