# How to Send timezone info to server with http request?

Tags: http, angular, asp.net-web-api, http-headers, timezone

I would like to do some timezone specific date manipulation on server. But I don't want to send the timezone via request payload for each and every http request. Any other work around there for achieve this? I use asp.net Web API for backend  and Angular 2 for front end.

Comment: You need to either send it on every request, or store it in server session state.  Why are you resistant to sending it as part of the request?

Comment: I don't want to set it explicitly with every request body. Is there any way to send with http headers?

Comment: Sure: `var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  this.http.post('http:/myurl', creds, {
    headers: headers
    })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a header to a specific request:

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('MyHeaderName','MyHeaderValue')
http.post('http://myurl', {/*body*/}, { headers: headers })
```

Alternatively, you could extend the http class and add a header to every request automatically, see here for details:

[What is httpinterceptor equivalent in angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498456/what-is-httpinterceptor-equivalent-in-angular2)

Comment: Thanks. I would look in to the http interceptor for angular 2.