# Call common function before and/or after HTTP request in angular 2

Tags: angular, httprequest, rxjs, loader, npm-request

I need to setup common loader into entire `angular2` project.
So i just want to do is when my new `http` call generate either it's GET, POST, or PUT then before request sent loader is appear.
Once `http` response(success or error) arrive from server side then loader should be disappear.

There is any in built module available using that i can do above functionality.
Or give me any way so i can do it with angular functions.
I am using `rxjs` for `http` request.

**I not want to use jQuery or Javascript.**

Answer (score 2):

Create http interceptor and call your common functions inside it. You may either write your own interceptor implementation [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35500055/7362128) or use [an external library](https://github.com/voliva/angular2-interceptors)

Answer (score 2):

Extending HTTP works well - in our project we also wanted explicit control of the 'loader' aka spinner for some scenarios.  So we have a *SpinnerService* in our Core [module](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html) that is available to all components.

```
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {

  private spinnerStateSource = new Subject<SpinnerState>();
  spinnerState$ = this.spinnerStateSource.asObservable();

  private defaultMessage: string = 'Loading...';

  show(message?: string) {

    let msg = this.defaultMessage as string;
    if (message) {
      msg = message;
    }

    this.spinnerStateSource.next({ showing: true, message: msg });
  }

  hide() {
    this.spinnerStateSource.next({ showing: false, message: '' });
  }

  spin(obs: Observable<any>, message?: string): Observable<any> {
    this.show(message);
    return obs.finally(() => this.hide());
  }

}

class SpinnerState {
  showing: boolean;
  message: string;
}
```

A component in the main module subscribes to the service to show/hide the actual spinner UI (EDIT: just like in @Gunter's answer), and other components can (via the service) tell the spinner to show/hide.

An example where we use that is if a component has to make multiple HTTP calls to e.g. get some reference data, then we want the spinner to show til all those calls are done. So we call the `spin` function with the action we are waiting on

e.g. in the consuming component:

```
this.spinnerService.spin(
     Observable.forkJoin(
       this.refDataService.getRefDataList('statusTypes'),
       this.refDataService.getRefDataList('itemTypes')
     )
 ).subscribe(result => {
             this.statusTypes = result[0];
             this.itemTypes = result[1];
 });
```

Comment: Here you used `SpinnerState`. What is it's default value ? I got error when i copy this code. Also what is `spinnerState$` ?

Comment: It's a type containing info to pass to the spinner - I've edited my post

Comment: It's work fine, but i need to import this service where i use it's method. Any way to set in common ? When any HTTP request is generate it will automatic call `spinnerService.spin` method, so i not need to call this method in every request.

Comment: If you want it to apply to all HTTP calls by default, you'd want to extend the standard http service (as described in the linked question added by @Slava), and inject the SpinnerService there. I'd imagine both the spinner and the 'custom' http service would be defined in a Core module.

Answer (score 1):

```ts
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  private change:Subject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
  public change$ = this.change.asObservable();

  constructor(private http:Http) {}

  get(...) {
    this.change.next(true)
    return this.http.get( ... )
    .map( ... )
    .finally(_ => this.change.next(false);
  }
}
```

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  template: `
  <div *ngIf="myService.change | async">is loading ...</div>
`
)}
class LoaderComponent {
  constructor(public myService:MyService){}
}
```