# Angular Interceptor: intercept Http instead of HttpClient

Tags: angular, http, alfresco, interceptor

My Angular application is using some Alfresco external library to render part of the front end component.

The component from the Alfresco library sends out request on rendering, and I like to intercept and modify it.

However, the interceptor fails to intercept and I suspect that the Alfresco library is using Http to send request. (The interceptor is already working for my custom request sent with HttpClient)

If my thought is correct, is there any way to capture the request send by Alfresco?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498456/what-is-httpinterceptor-equivalent-in-angular2/35500055#35500055?

Comment: If you are talking about extending the Http class, this extension doesn't apply to my case because I probably have to stick with the original class.

Comment: we can probably extend the whole set of component classes. But is there a simpler way?

Comment: `Http.prototype.request = your override`

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are external Alfresco libraries that you are using? Are these angular components?