# Change the request body in interceptor angular2

Tags: angular, request, inspector

How can I change the request body type of post in interceptor?

For example I have this object:

```
{"UserName":"213243546","Password":"89876"}
```

that I want to change all `3` to `e` but it is not only in this request that I have this, I should search in each post request with every single data and objects that it might have or not and change all `3` to `e` is that possible in angular 2 to do that by clone or HttpRequest
or inspector or . .

I already see [this URL](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest) but I couldn't get much out of it.

Comment: For Angular, not AngularJS, you can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498456/what-is-httpinterceptor-equivalent-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

You can create an interceptor like this:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {

  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($log, $injector, $location) {
    return({
       request: request,
       requestError: requestError,
       response: response,
       responseError: responseError
    });

   function request(config) {    

            // place your code logic inside here

            return config;
    }

    function requestError(rejection) {
        $log.debug(rejection);
        return $q.reject(rejection);  
    }
  });

}]);
```

You can then modify the config object!