# Angular 2 : Redirect to a page at application startup

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm facing a little issue for my web application in Angular 2.

Each application launch, I would check if the user has a right of access.
However I don't know how to redirect the user to the route which makes this process whatever the place where he is.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are two common ways

- use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/CanActivate-decorator.html)
- use a custom [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterOutlet-directive.html)

  where you check if the user is authenticated otherwise redirect to the login route

See also
- [Check if the user logged in on any page change in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420033/check-if-the-user-logged-in-on-any-page-change-in-angular-2/36420189#36420189)
- http://www.captaincodeman.com/2016/03/31/angular2-route-security/

Comment: it seems that angular does not handle redirections easily .. Many efforts just to force the first page of my application...
I will try these two methods, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `OnInit` interface and add redirection/check in `ngOnInit` method and add `@CanActivate` to your child components:

```
class Static{
   static authenticated:boolean = false;
   static initialized:boolean = false;
}

@CanActivate(()=>{
   if(Static.authenticated && Static.initialized){
      return true;
   }
   return false;
})

protected ngOnInit():any
{
    this.loginFacade.refresh().subscribe(event=>
    {
        var url = event.success ? this.location.path() : Routes.LOGIN;

        Static.authenticated = event.success;

        this.router.recognize(url).then(()=>
        {
            return Promise.resolve(url);
        }, (e)=>
        {
            return Promise.resolve(Routes.LOGIN);
        }).then((url)=>
        {
            Static.initialized = true;
            return this.router.navigateByUrl(url);
        });
    });
}
```

also remove default route.

Comment: OnInit is called but I can't use the router in my main class... I have error "cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined". Thanks for your answer

Comment: I tried your solution in my class App which is called by Bootstrap..And it seems that we can't make redirects in this class