# How to set permissions on URL?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am wondering how I can set permissions on the URL that user is trying to access. I have already disabled buttons and other elements that may navigate him, based on permissions that I receive from backend, but I would also like to unable him to navigate to those pages by URL.

Thanks

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698454/angular2-redirect-to-a-page-at-application-startup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different ways:

- use [CanActivate](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)
- use a custom [RouterOutlet](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

where you redirect to the login route if not authenticated.

See also [Check if the user logged in on any page change in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420033/check-if-the-user-logged-in-on-any-page-change-in-angular-2/36420189#36420189)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the Günter's answer, you could also try the following things:

- Apply a directive to the `routerLink` to display / hide it based on permissions
- Extend the `Http` class to check permissions globally before executing HTTP requests.

See this question for more details:

- [Check if the user logged in on any page change in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420033/check-if-the-user-logged-in-on-any-page-change-in-angular-2/36420261#36420261)